# Sqlboiler define relations

Tags: go, orm

I have a sqlite database for which I need read only access in go. I have been exploring sqlboiler as an ORM and it's been great so far generating the models etc but 1 thing I was not able to figure out is how to define custom relations. I know that it does this automatically when the db has foreign keys etc but my db doesn't and I can't change its structure (it's written by another application). So I have a structure like this:

books:

```
id  |  title
1   | Sample title
```

authors:

```
id | name
1  | Author Name
```

book_authors:

```
book_id | author_id
1       | 1
```

I think it's fairly obvious what I want to do, this is a many to many relation between books and authors. The problem is that book_id and author_id are not foreign keys. Is there any way I can configure the code generation inside the toml file to create this relation or will I have to write code manually to do that? Thanks